# Как сделать чтобы .bat файл закрывался через определнное кол-во времени?

Tags: python, bat

Подскажите пожалуйста,возможно ли так сделать?Чтобы программа запущенная через батник работала допустим 3600 сек. и потом закрывалась?

Comment: Думаю это как раз то что нужно https://stackoverflow.com/q/4084322/13794578

Answer (score 2):

Что именно хочется достичь непонятно.
**Вариант 1:**
Использовать `timeout <second>` и `exit`.
**Вариант 2:**
Использовать планировщик задач, где в параметрах указать если задача выполняется дольше определенного времени, то прекращать её.